# The target table of the UPDATE is not updatable

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run this query :

```
UPDATE TempRH T 
    JOIN (
           SELECT offices_id,MAX(Poids)AS Poids
           FROM TempRH  
           GROUP BY 
                  offices_id
          )T1
    ON T1.offices_id=T.offices_id
    SET T1.Poids=0
```

but on execution it gives an error:

```
#1288-The target table T1 of the UPDATE is not updatable.
```

Any solutions?

Comment: @user3014966. Tell us what you really want to do. That query working would put poids = 0 in every row on the table.

Comment: How are you using MAX(Poids) ? You can't update an agregation result

Comment: you are trying to update the table you are joining on not the one you indicate to update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me a small change would fix this?

```
UPDATE TempRH T 
    JOIN (
           SELECT offices_id,MAX(Poids)AS Poids
           FROM TempRH  
           GROUP BY 
                  offices_id
          )T1
    ON T1.offices_id=T.offices_id
    SET T.Poids=0
```

Change `T1.Poids` to `T.Poids`. So you `SET` a value on the `TABLE` you want to `UPDATE`

Comment: This will still put 0 in poids for all the rows in the table, but maybe that's what he wants :). This could easily be done with `UPDATE tempRH Set poids=0;`

Comment: This i didnt reflect on as i immediatley saw why the table couldnt be updated. But yes, you are right Filipe :)

Comment: I would say a `HAVING Count(Poids) > a_number` would make sense in this query, otherwise, simply set `Poids=0` like you say!